# Infinite lists in haskell using predefined functions

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner in Haskell and I'm trying to make a simple program that takes a list e.g `[-3,8]` and makes the infinite list: `[-3,8,-3,8,-3,8,...]`

Thanks to Haskell's lazy evaluation I've written a very simple program that computes it:

```
period :: [a]->[a]
period p = p ++ period p
```

I would like to know if exists a more simple solution using high order functions (iterate, map,...)

Comment: Consider using [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) the next time. It's a search engine for Haskell. You can search by name or by type (see the linked search and how the first result is exactly `cycle`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first place to look for list functions in general is `Data.List`. There you will find

```
cycle :: [a] -> [a]
```

which does exactly what you want. However, it is defined a little differently, so as to make a circular linked list instead of an infinite one. Something like

```
cycle xs = ys where ys = xs ++ ys
```

This can avoid a lot of unnecessary memory allocation. You can express this definition using `Data.Function.fix`:

```
cycle xs = fix (xs ++)
```

If you love to over-generalize, you can define this for general `Semigroup`s using

```
cycle xs = fix (xs <>)
```

though this will diverge for most semigroups.

If you're a point-free fanatic, you can translate this to

```
cycle xs = fix ((<>) xs)
```

which you can then see is

```
cycle = fix . (<>)
```

Comment: The beauty of `fix . (<>)` makes the point-free fanatic in me cry, but this is pretty neat even from a pragmatic perspective.

Comment: `forever :: Applicative f => f a -> f b` if we imagine the ability to use it [`via` the behaviour of `Const`](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/218) we get `cycle = forever @(via Const) :: Monoid m => m -> m`

Comment: @Iceland_jack without that, it's still not at all bad. `cycle = getConst . forever . Const`, or `cycle = under Const forever`. Speaking of which, have you seen [my latest creation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/coercible-utils-0.1.0/docs/CoercibleUtils-Newtype.html)? There are some challenges improving the error messages, but I think it's already interesting.

Comment: Yes I saw it dfeuer, it's a nice `coerce` and combinator solution to this. Also McBride's idea of providing type information with an otherwise ignored argument is the best solution I've found so far

Comment: @Iceland_jack, my own innovation was limited to the `Similar` class; everything else was invented elsewhere. BTW, it would be possible to add a version of `ala'` that passes a usefully polymorphic packer. I think I'll add that....